# Reinstalling python on Mac OS 10.6 with a different gcc version

Tags: python, gcc

I am trying to install a Python package that requires running gcc 4.2.  My gcc is pointing correctly to gcc-4.2, i.e.

```
$ gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
Target: i686-apple-darwin10
Configured with: /var/tmp/gcc/gcc-5664~38/src/configure --disable-checking --enable-werror --prefix=/usr --mandir=/share/man --enable-languages=c,objc,c++,obj-c++ --program-transform-name=/^[cg][^.-]*$/s/$/-4.2/ --with-slibdir=/usr/lib --build=i686-apple-darwin10 --program-prefix=i686-apple-darwin10- --host=x86_64-apple-darwin10 --target=i686-apple-darwin10 --with-gxx-include-dir=/include/c++/4.2.1
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5664)
```

However, my python is built using gcc 4.0, i.e.

```
$ python
Python 2.5.4 (r254:67917, Dec 23 2008, 15:47:06) 
[GCC 4.0.1 (Apple Inc. build 5363)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

Is there any way I can re-build Python on GCC 4.2 *without* having to reinstall all my Python packages?

My operating system is Mac OS 10.6.

NOTE: It will not help me to just point gcc to gcc-4.0 -- I need to use gcc-4.2.

Comment: What package is it? C source in packages depends on the system's compiler, not what the python executable was compiled with. Sounds like an errant check in the package that could be patched.

Comment: Sorry, it's tired and I'm late. The issue would be with distutils, not the package being built.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On current OS X Pythons, Distutils tries to ensure that C extension modules are built using the same GCC and `MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET` (ABI) as the Python interpreter itself was.  This ensures that there won't be conflicts with the underlying system libraries.

But if you are on OS X 10.6, then the Python version you show is not one of the Apple-supplied Pythons, both of which *are* built with gcc-4.2.  Chances are you have an older python.org 2.5 also installed with symlinks into `/usr/local/bin`.

```
# OS X 10.6.4
$ /usr/bin/python -c 'import sys;print(sys.version)'
2.6.1 (r261:67515, Feb 11 2010, 00:51:29) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5646)]
$ /usr/bin/python2.6 -c 'import sys;print(sys.version)'  # same as above
2.6.1 (r261:67515, Feb 11 2010, 00:51:29) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5646)]
$ /usr/bin/python2.5 -c 'import sys;print(sys.version)'
2.5.4 (r254:67916, Feb 11 2010, 00:50:55) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5646)]
$ /usr/local/bin/python2.5 -c 'import sys;print(sys.version);print(sys.executable)'
2.5.4 (r254:67917, Dec 23 2008, 14:57:27) 
[GCC 4.0.1 (Apple Computer, Inc. build 5363)]
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
```

`which python` will tell you which Python is being invoked. Either use an absolute path to the interpreter you want or change your shell PATH or remove the old Python 2.5.

Comment: @NedDeily I've posted a follow-up question to this answer. Would you mind taking a look? http://stackoverflow.com/q/14720702/1337422

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely an issue with distutils, you shouldn't need to recompile python, or reinstall any packages.

Have you checked to see what version your `CC` environment variable is set to? It may very well still be set to 4.0. You can try:

```
export CC=gcc-4.2
python setup.py build
```

You could also take a look at:

`/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/lib/python2.5/config/Makefile`

Which is where distutils gets its build settings from.