# Getting python malloc segmentation fault when start running django runserver after update macOS to High Sierra

Tags: python, django, macos

I'm struggling to run Django app server in my local.
And it does not work since I've updated my macOS to High Sierra from Sierra yesterday morning.

I'm using

> Django 1.10.5
>   Python 2.7.14

[image]

When I run the `./manage.py runserver`, it shows the error message like below.

```
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
python(4381,0x70000269c000) malloc: *** error for object -x7fe76b38a860: Non-aligned pointer being freed (2)
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
[1]    4359 abort      ./manage.py runserver
```

And I found one issue from here [Dynamic library problems with Python and libstdc++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7561640/dynamic-library-problems-with-python-and-libstdc) the error message looks quite similar, but couldn't find any similarity so far.

Comment: You should probably recreate your virtualenv and reinstall your dependencies.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
Actually, I tried already and I even re-install my macOS to Yosemite, but still having the same problem.
Also, I find out that it only happens when the Django ORM is evaluating (getting object stuff)